# Is it possible in NET to get the Object Reference (instance not the Class) of the caller within a method being called using ContextBoundObject

Tags: c#, .net

Using stack trace can give only the class not the instance of the caller. So I wondered if there is a solution using ContextBoundObject since problem is about context.

But ContextBoundObject seems very complex to understand I cannot understand how to use it so does someone knows if it is possible ?

Update: I'm not interested about AOP here just in getting the reference to the object instance that calls a method. AOP is different from my question so I don't think article with AOP does answer my question but I have the "intuition" that ContextBoundObject could be an answer but I'm not sure so my question :)

Can you imagine in real world if you couldn't know who is calling you by phone :) A programming language should expose the caller instance because it can be needed for some use cases.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried till now?

Comment: You might want to un-tag AOP then, eh :)

Comment: @Amit Mittal, let's say I want to logging caller instance properties or call back some method on it.

Comment: If it's really needed, you can always pass the instance as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is impossible because of method inlining and garbage collection.

Comment: Why? How .NET runtime can do itself to execute a method on an instance if he wouldn't have any reference to that instance ? How could he intercept method call without reference to that object instance ? If .Net runtime can have this reference why couldn't it make available (and if context is not valid just throw some exceptions) ?

Comment: Can you imagine in real world if you couldn't know who is calling you by phone :) A programming language should expose the caller instance because it can be needed for some use cases.